# Laravel spatie permission assign super admin with multiple guards

Tags: laravel, permissions, laravel-permission

what: i want to assign all permissions for each guard'

i have three guards unit, pack and troop, each has the same permissions assigned create, edit, delete, and view, for a set feature.

I was using this to set all permissions when only using a single guard (web).

```
Role::create(['name' => 'super-admin'])
            ->givePermissionTo(Permission::all());
```

how do i create a super admin with all permissions from each guard.